# Is it possible to change the iPhone app icon and title once it's installed?

Tags: ios

I've seen some apps where you can customized the theme, fonts when you open the app and go to some menu like Settings.  But is it possible, say in the Settings, for user to change the app icon and title the way he wants the icon to be displayed in his phone?

Comment: if it was possible, user might get confused looking for the app he installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iphone app change its home screen icon and name after installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255922/can-an-iphone-app-change-its-home-screen-icon-and-name-after-installation) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005007/dynamic-icon-change-for-iphone?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the iPhone app icon and title once it's installed?

Short answer is **`NO`**, it is not possible because your app icon and title are available in app `NSBundle` and apple said that if you made any changes with `NSBundle` when your app installed then apple will be reject you app.

Comment: Now this is possible with iOS 10.3. More details available here http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/01/26/ios-10-3-will-let-apps-change-their-home-screen-icon-at-any-time-no-update-required/

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible because your application icon and application name are listed in application bundle so it want be changed once installed so not possible.